# SUMIF wildcard in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

This is the standard expression for `SUMIF`:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A10,"Paid",B1:B10)
```

But it is possible to add wildcard like:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A10,"*A2*",B1:B10)
```

where `A2` is a cell in the sheet?

I'd like to change the value in `A2` and get the result instead of typing the formula.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
SUMIF(A1:A10,"*"&A2&"*",B1:B10)
```